# Do custom validator need ServerValidate event if it already has clientValidationFunction

Tags: asp.net, validation, customvalidator

As far as i know, If there is clientValidationFunction in a customer validator. it will not let the post back happen until the value is valid. So if there is clientValidationFunction already, it is not needed to have a ServerValidate event right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *never* rely on client-side code alone to perform validation. The client might have scripting disabled, so your validation code may not run at all. Moreover, client-side code can also be circumvented in many other ways.

Client-side validation is useful to avoid a round-trip to the server when a field is invalid, but you *still* have to perform server-side validation to actually ensure the client has sent valid data.

Answer (score 1):

That is right in case you are trying to fire an event of a control with a `CausesValidation` property that has been set to *true*. However, if `CausesValidation` has been set to *false* a *Post Back* is going to happened.

You can force the validator to call its validation logic even if the `CausesValidation` has been set to *false* by call `validator.Validate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Server validation should be used when you can't create - because of complexity - a client rule. Here you can read some [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx)